# Is their any relation between stiefel-whitney class and obstruction to lift SO(3) to SU(2)?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I found a paper by kirby and taylor [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kirbytaylorpin.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/kirbytaylorpin.pdf). It is said that the obstruction to lift O(n) bundle to $pin(n)_-$ bundle is some stiefel-whitney class. So, is there any similar conclusion for lift SO(n) to spin(n).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2(P)\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ of a principal $\text{SO}(n)$-bundle $P$ is the obstruction to lifting $P$ to a principal $\text{Spin}(n)$-bundle $\widetilde{P}$.

Let $\rho:\text{Spin}(n)\to\text{SO}(n)$ be the double covering map. Given transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha\beta}\to\text{SO}(n)$ for $P$, we consider lifts $\tau_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha\beta}\to\text{Spin}(n)$ with the property that $\rho(\tau_{\alpha\beta})=g_{\alpha\beta}$, as well as $\tau_{\alpha\beta}=\tau_{\beta\alpha}^{-1}$. For these $\tau_{\alpha\beta}$ to define a spin structure over $X$, they also need to satisfy the cocycle condition. We define a Cech $2$-cochain as $\tau_{\alpha\beta}\tau_{\beta\gamma}\tau_{\gamma\alpha}=f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}I$. Since $\rho(\tau_{\alpha\beta}\tau_{\beta\gamma}\tau_{\gamma\alpha})=1$, we have $f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}\in\ker\rho=\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then you can verify that $[f]:=w_2(P)\in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, and this class is independent of the local frame, as well as the choice of lift to $\text{Spin}(n)$. The requirement that $[f]=1$ is precisely the requirement that $\tau_{\alpha\beta}$ can be chosen in such a way as to satisfy the cocycle condition. Thus, $w_2(P)$ is the obstruction to lifting an $\text{SO}(n)$-structure to a $\text{Spin}(n)$-structure.